# const in std::function template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Why does this fail to compile in G++ 5.3.1 (with --std=c++1y):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename InputIterator>
void foo(InputIterator i, std::function<bool(typename const std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type&)> f)
{
    cout << f(*i) << endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3 };
    foo(v.begin(), [] (const int& a) -> bool { return false; } );
}
```

This fails with the message:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"source.d" -MT"source.o" -o "source.o" "../source.cc"
../source.cc:16:110: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 void foo(InputIterator i, std::function<bool(typename const std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type&)> f)
                                                                                                              ^
../source.cc:16:110: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../source.cc:16:110: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../source.cc:16:110: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../source.cc:16:110: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../source.cc:16:32: error: ‘std::function’ is not a type
 void foo(InputIterator i, std::function<bool(typename const std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type&)> f)
                                ^
../source.cc:16:40: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void foo(InputIterator i, std::function<bool(typename const std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type&)> f)
                                        ^
../source.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
../source.cc:23:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::vector<int>::iterator, main()::<lambda(const int&)>)’
  foo(v.begin(), [] (const int& a) -> bool { return false; } );
                                                             ^
../source.cc:16:6: note: candidate: template<class InputIterator> void foo(InputIterator, int)
 void foo(InputIterator i, std::function<bool(typename const std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type&)> f)
      ^
../source.cc:16:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../source.cc:23:61: note:   cannot convert ‘<lambda closure object>main()::<lambda(const int&)>{}’ (type ‘main()::<lambda(const int&)>’) to type ‘int’
  foo(v.begin(), [] (const int& a) -> bool { return false; } );
                                                             ^
```

(Note line numbers are off by 8 due to some header comments which I've omitted).

But if I remove all the `const` qualifiers then it compiles fine.

Comment: `const` and `typename` should be the other way round; or else, move `const` to the right, after `value_type` and before the ampersand. `typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type` is the name of the type you are modifying; you need to keep all parts of it together.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `const typename ...` instead of  `typename const ...` :)

Comment: And this because e.g. `const int*` and `int* const` are two very different types.

Comment: @rubenvb In this case it's more like `const unsigned int` is a valid type, but `unsigned const int` is syntactical nonsense.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `unsigned const int` is not syntactical nonsense, it compiles just fine. The example is not equivalent because `std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type` is a typedef, which makes rubenvb's example more correct.